# How to turn off Google reCAPTCHA localization or lock to English

Tags: javascript, html, localization, recaptcha

I tried `&hl=en-GB` and this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
lang : 'en-GB'
};
</script>
```

But it won't turn off localization. Is there any type of technique that I can restrict the language or stop localization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was how you changed the language for reCAPTHCA v1

For v2 you can override in JavaScript like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en-GB"></script>
```

Or you can omit it from JavaScript all together and append it to your key in PHP

```
define('RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY', '__YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE__&amp;hl=en-GB');
```